# Why does the nullPrintStream() function in java/lang/System compare currentTimeMillis() to zero?

Tags: jvm, java

When loading the System class, the `<clinit>` method instantiates the `in`, `out` and `err` `PrintStream` variables to `null` using the `nullPrintStream()` method:

```
private static PrintStream nullPrintStream() throws NullPointerException {
    if (currentTimeMillis() > 0) {
        return null;
    }
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

I understand why this is the case, and why the variables cannot be instantiated during loading, but what I'm confused about is the content of that method.

Why is it comparing `currentTimeMillis()` to `0`? In what case would that comparison ever return `false`?

Comment: If you travel back in time to 31/12/1969 :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Javadoc for the nullPrintStream() method gives a clue:

> The compiler, however, cannot be permitted to
>        inline access to them, since they are later set to more sensible values
>        by initializeSystemClass().

This is a coding hack, I guess, to prevent the compiler from inlining a simple "return null" implementation.

currentTimeMillis() will never be less than 0. But the compiler isn't clever enough to know that, and therefore leaves the conditional statement intact.

Comment: `to prevent the compiler from inlining a simple "return null" implementation.` why would you want to prevent that? If anything it makes more sense as a sanity check to me.

Comment: More code-diving shows that a native method sets the field values to more sensible, non-null values later. But the compiler doesn't know that the native code will interfere with the fields of java.lang.System. It is hacky, messy, and probably a relic.

Comment: A@rtB, if the compiler inlined a `null` value you couldn't use `System.out` and that would be bad. ;)

Comment: Hmm, this makes sense I guess. What exactly does inlining a `null` value mean? That the reference will be assumed to always be `null`? @SteveMcLeod, I know the values are set natively, but that's necessary so that they can be `public static final` and yet still be instantiated after loading I believe.

Comment: `null` is not a compile time constant, it cannot be inlined, can it?

Comment: The important thing to note is that `System.out`/`err`/`in` are special cases: They are `final` fields that *can* change during normal operation (using `setOut`/`setErr`/`setIn`).